# How to open a save dialogue in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm using the below code

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="file" id="fileDialog" style="opacity: 0">
```

**JS Code**

```
event.preventDefault();
$("#fileDialog").trigger('click');
```

But this is opening File Explorer as shown in image
[File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzTyH.png)

I want to open a File Explorer with Save Button not an open Button, can anyone help me with this please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Answer (score 0):

I think that web pages open Save dialog only when the user wants to download something. The page have not access to the file system of the local computer. If want to save something js do it in browsers storage eg. indexed db, cookie, session storage... eg.:

```
      let p = { color: 'yellow' };
      let key = 'color';
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(p));
```

Comment: I want to download the pdf generated